Swift 6 iOS 18 fix small sheets?
Update to Swift 6 iOS 18 and .sheet is now presented as small compared to previous versions on the iPad. I attempted to fix with the modifier .presentationDetents([.large], selection: $selectedDetent) to set the sheet size .large, but it didn't work. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to have the sheets display how they use to.
Notice the left is Swift 6 on iOS 17, while the right screenshot is Swift6 on iOS 18.


Use presentationSizing to set the size of the sheet. Sheets before iOS 18 seem to be .page by default, so you can use that.
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    Text("Something")
        .presentationSizing(.page)
}

You can also declare your own sizings:
struct CustomSizing: PresentationSizing {
    func proposedSize(for root: PresentationSizingRoot, context: PresentationSizingContext) -> ProposedViewSize {
        .init(width: 200, height: 300)
    }
}


I made a view extension like this:
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func presentationSizingPage() -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, macOS 15.0, tvOS 18.0, visionOS 2.0, watchOS 11.0, *) {
            self.presentationSizing(.page)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

It can then be used as a view modifier '.presentationSizingPage()'

Discovered I can just set a .frame within the .sheet and manually set the size to 85% of the screen size produces similar results as the old sheet.
.sheet(isPresented: $Open) {
    VStack{
        Text("test")
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.85, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.85)
}

